# Flutter ListView.Builder pulling works on iOS but not on Android

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  late ScrollController _controller;
  bool pulling = false;

  Future<void> _refresh() async {

  _scrollListener() async {
    //for right end
    if (_controller.offset - _controller.position.maxScrollExtent >= 100 &&
        !pulling) {
      setState(() {
        pulling = true;
      });
    }
    if (_controller.offset - _controller.position.maxScrollExtent < 10.0 &&
        pulling) {
      setState(() {
        pulling = false;
      });
      _controller.animateTo(
        _controller.position.minScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      );
      await _refresh();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _controller.dispose();
  }


ListView.builder(
  controller: _controller,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (c, i) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
      child: Container,
    );
  },
),
```

I have this code to do a 'pull-to-refresh'. It works on iOS device, however, it does not work on Android and wondering why is this the case or if I had made any error?

Comment: Just a code review: In `initState`, you should call `super.initState()` first before the other; and in `dispose`, you should call `super.dispose()` last (you did it the other way around)

Comment: Also, why did you make your own pull-to-refresh, instead of using [`RefreshIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, the [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) package is excellent. I recommend trying it out, as it works seamlessly on both Android and iOS platforms.